# Reactjs AWS Cognito - How to Handle newPasswordRequired

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito Javascript SDK in a react application. I have a user that was created in the AWS Console by an admin. The user recieves an email with their username and temporary password. Now based on my understanding, I have to go through the newPasswordRequired flow, but I have been struggling with this for several hours now trying multiple different approaches and none are getting me anywhere. When I check the AWS Console, the user in the user pool is set to FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD.

Here is my code in its current state. Please if someone can help me solve the process as I am fairly new to using Cognito authentication.

```
function setNewPassword(data) {
  console.log("data \n", data)
  var authenticationData = {
    Username: data.username,
    Password: data.temp_password
  };
  var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(
    authenticationData
  );
  var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(config.cognito);
  var userData = {
    Username: data.username,
    Pool: userPool
  };
  var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: function(result) {
        resolve(resolve);
      },
      onFailure: function(err) {
        reject(err);
      },
      newPasswordRequired: function(userAttributes, requiredAttributes) {
        this.cognitoUser.completeNewPasswordChallenge(newPassword, attributesData, this)
      }
    });
  });
}
```

In the browser console, I am getting the following error:

```
{code: "UnknownError", message: "Unkown error"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using the AWS Amplify JS library for help here?  There's a suite of React components already built to help with these sorts of things. Here's a link to [the relevant documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#using-the-authenticator-component-directly). The code is open sourced on GitHub and you might be able to just use the [RequireNewPassword component](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/aws-amplify-react/src/Auth/RequireNewPassword.jsx), or at least find inspiration from it.